# Is my graphics driver not compatible with Ubuntu 15.10?

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, graphics-card, display

My system is an eight-year old desktop. It has the [following configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnQ0L.png).

- Memory: 1.9GB
- Processor: Intel Pentium Dual Core E2140 @ 1.6GHz
- Graphics: Intel 945G
- OS Type: 64-bit
- Disk: 155.3GB

I am using an LG Flatron E2042 Monitor. 
During work, the screen starts flickering frequently. It looks like this:

[image: Flickering Screen]

Today, I got the following error message:

```
fsck from util-linux 2.26.2
/dev/sda1: clean...
[OK] Started Light Display Manager.
[OK] Started ACPI event daemon.
```

What could be the most probable cause of such an error?

Comment: An Intel 945 is ancient. I wouldn't be surprised if this was just a component dying over time. Could be a dry joint or any number of related failures.

Comment: Have you just upgraded ?   Can you try a different monitor (I don't think the monitor is dying, but it might be the EDID information is sending resolutions the monitor can't handle).  I'd think the most probable cause would be an incorrect modeline or incorrect driver.

Comment: Yes, I also belived there was an issue with the driver but I updated the driver to the latest version available.

Comment: Also, the monitor is old but there was no major issue when I was using Windows on my machine.